# Expect100Continue in .NET 4.5

Tags: .net-4.5

How can I disable expect100continue in .net 4.5?
Earlier I could write

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

But now there's no such class in .NET 4.5 Client Profile (information from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.expect100continue.aspx))

Comment: There is no such thing as a ".NET 4.5 Client Profile", that was a mistake in 4.0 they didn't repeat.  The property is alive and well in 4.5.  But wouldn't be available in, say, a Windows Store app or Portable Class Library project.

Comment: @HansPassant so is there an alternative available for Windows Store app?

Comment: The Apple or Android store?  Make up your mind about what kind of program you want to write first.  If you want to use this property then you'll have to write a Windows desktop app.